# WSO2 ESB, defining sequence, practical tutorial is needed

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm new to WSO2 and the whole concept. I have many web services in WSO2 Application Server and I want to integrate them using Proxy service in WSO2 ESB.
I create WSDL that defines my virtual service (proxy service), now I have problem to continue I mean I can't find practical tutorial that shows how can I integrate my existing web services with each other, manage their out puts and generate my arbitrary output. In fact I don't know what are sequences do exactly, how can I fire a web service within a sequence and add it's result to my existing output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callout mediator to call an external webservice inside a sequence and obtain a response, for that please follow below links.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Callout+Mediator

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+430%3A+Simple+Callout+Mediator+for+Synchronized+Web+Service+Invocation

Further you can use payload factory mediator or enrich mediators to manipulate messages based on results you get if you need.

Following blogs have nice use cases on service chaining which you might be interested.

http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining

http://dakshithar.blogspot.com/2012/06/routing-and-service-chaining-with-wso2.html

You can find all the existing mediators [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Mediators)

Comment: I used payload Factory and send mediators, I made my request using payload factory and sent it to pre-defined endpoint using send mediator. Then I create a sequence and manipulate the response it that sequence and set that sequence as receiver sequence in definition of my send mediator.